# Preventing Early Assignment on Vertical Spread

Tags: options

Is there a way to prevent early assignment on the short leg of a vertical spread?

Seeing all the responses leads me to the following edit: My biggest concern is to try an anticipate and avoid a worst case scenario where one leg of the spread is executed independently of the other with enough time lapsing to allow changes in the underlying and making the value of the position worthless or, worse yet causing a deep loss. If holding options overnight, when high volatility is expected, e.g. earnings release, is there a chance of assignment during that time?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent early assignment for an *American* style option.

It is up to the holder of the option when he chooses to exercise and for whatever reason.  It is then up to the clearing house to allocate those exercises to the brokers whose accounts are holding open interest, and then up to the broker to allocate those assignments to the respective accounts.

As @BobBaerker suggests in his answer, you can try to estimate when an early assignment takes place, and you can monitor your likelihood of getting assigned in certain circumstances but there is nothing you can do to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Short options are frequently exercised early by the owner if they are in-the-money and there is no time premium remaining.  It's even more likely if the option  trades  below parity (the option's bid < intrinsic value).  If the option  owner  sells at this inferior price,  the market maker will do a discount arbitrage to realize the difference (short the stock and exercise the call  OR buy the stock and exercise the put).  The option call owner can also do this to avoid the haircut,  assuming the size of the haircut is less than the commissions and/or fees involved.

A pending dividend can also precipitate early assignment:

- Because owners of ITM calls do no receive the dividend, they tend to sell before the ex-div date when share price will be reduced by the amount of the dividend. If that selling drives the premium below parity, it presents an opportunity for Discount Arbitrage (see above).
- If the time premium of an ITM put is less than the amount of the dividend, it offers a  dividend arbitrage.  The put and the stock are bought and the put is exercised on  the ex-dividend date, capturing the difference.

So the short answer to your question is that if there is time premium remaining in your short option, it's unlikely that it will be assigned early because doing so would throw away the time premium.  If your short option approaches parity (no time premium remaining), it's time to roll or close it if you don't want assignment.

Comment: There's a big difference between your two examples of "A pending dividend can also precipitate early assignment". The first (call) will *routinely* happen if the dividend is large enough. The second (put) is unusual and is not correlated with a dividend but rather with the interest rate. At any time, a deep-in-the-money put is likely to be exercised early only if the carry cost of the underlying exceeds the corresponding call premium (uncommon with today's low rates). ...

Comment: ... In your arbitrage, on the ex-dividend date, if this condition does *not* hold, the trader won't exercise the put but will hold it (or offset it with another position). If interest rates are low enough, waiting to see if the stock might luckily surge is better than exercising the put immediately. In any case, this decision is made *after* the stock goes ex-dividend and the dividend has no effect on it.

Comment: The size of the dividend does not precipitate a call arbitrage.  In fact, there is no possible dividend arbitrage with a call that has time premium remaining.  It is the call trading below parity that facilitates a **discount arbitrage**.  As for the ITM put, holding the stock in the hope of an unexpected surge in the price of the stock is a subsequent  investment decision that has nothing to do with the ability to lock in a risk free gain via a discounted put dividend arbitrage.

Comment: The original question was about likelihood of early exercise. With a large enough dividend, a short call position is practically guaranteed to be assigned. For a put, in the limit of zero interest rate, early exercise is *irrational*, at least for professional traders, whether as part of arbitrage or otherwise. For example, a stock+DITM put position (with put trading at or below intrinsic value) requires zero portfolio margin because there is no possibility of loss. So there is not even a liquidity cost to keeping the position to expiration in hopes of a gain, and no reason to exercise.

Comment: This is the theory on puts -- it would be good to know empirically whether early exercise of puts in zero-rate environments is indeed extremely rare.